# Mysql - Combine 2 SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries which return 2 result sets.
How can i combine these 2 queries to get one single result?

First Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Base base
INNER JOIN Child child ON child.base_id = base.id
where base.`status` = "active" and base.application = "template";
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Base base
WHERE base.`status` = "active" and base.application = "template" and base.role = "public" ;
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you want one single result, or one single result set?

Comment: one single result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4....
FROM Base base
INNER JOIN Child child ON child.base_id = base.id
where base.`status` = "active" and base.application = "template"

UNION

SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4....
FROM Base base
WHERE base.`status` = "active" and base.application = "template" and base.role = "public" ;
```

Note that if you want to have the duplicate elements from the two queries then you can use `UNION ALL`.

Also make sure that the number of columns should be same for both the query result when using `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks for this. now i need to convert this to php. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM Base base
INNER JOIN Child child ON child.base_id = base.id
WHERE ( base.`status` = "active" 
AND base.application = "template" )or (base.`status` = "active" and base.application = "template" and base.role = "public");
```

Comment: i tried this one but this does not return the correct results.

Comment: Can You pls Explain What You need the exauct Result

Comment: I have made a Edit...Check now